# Understanding (->) r as instance of Reader

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

So I'm told `(->) r` is an instance of the Reader monad, but I can't seem to find any concrete examples of how this is supposed to work. I want to use this without having to explicitly wrap some of my code in a Reader

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

testOne :: Reader String String
testOne = do
  env <- ask
  return $ "Hello, " ++ env

testTwo :: String -> String
testTwo = do
  env <- ask
  return $ "G'day, " ++ env
```

Running `runReader testOne "there"` works fine, but running `runReader testTwo "mate"` fails spectacularly with the following message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘String -> String’
                   with ‘ReaderT [Char] Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a’
    Expected type: Reader [Char] a
      Actual type: String -> String
```

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you **want** `runReader testTwo "mate"` to be a valid syntax for producing anything, as distinct from, say, `id testTwo "mate"`? Note that `(->) r` is not an "instance of the Reader monad" but rather that it is a "monad which does the exact same thing as the Reader monad." But we need to know in order to help you: are you interfacing with something which will take a `Reader r x` as an argument? Or do you need code which is polymorphic and will both accept a `Reader r x` and an `r -> x` function? Or what?

Comment: @CRDrost it was more of a "in case I have something that uses both things" kinda question, having one unified runner would be useful. But I guess since the entire question is guided by a misleading statement, I don't really need it?

Answer (score 3):

The type of `runReader` is `runReader :: ReaderT r Identity -> r -> a`, if you expand out the `newtype Reader = ReaderT r Identity`. I think you want something very generic, along the lines of this:

```
foo :: (MonadReader r m) => m a -> r -> a
```

So that you could evaluate both `foo testOne "there"` and `foo testTwo "mate"`.

Unfortunately, no such function exists. The `mtl` library's job is to abstract the choice of the underlying concrete type. Both `(->) String` and `Reader String = ReaderT String Identity` are concrete types that obey the `Monad` and `MonadReader` laws, but that only guarantees you an interface of `return`, `>>=`, `ask`, `reader`, and `local` (and `<$>`, `<*>`, `pure`).

This is both limiting and useful!

Limiting: In order to "run" the computation represented by either type, you need to use the appropriate type-specific API. For `(->) String`, that's simply calling the function (the invisible  function application operator); for `Reader String`, that's `runReader`.

Useful: you can expose, with a library, values constrained by `MonadReader`, knowing that users will only be able to use them with the `MonadReader` interface. This is nice, as you can use this trick to make sure that users aren't doing anything untoward, like doing early runs of your values with their own environments (`r`'s).

Answer (score 2):

`runReader :: Reader r a -> r -> a` is specifically for `Reader` newtype, which you want to avoid. Since `testTwo` is just a function, you simply use `testTwo "mate"`.

If you want a generic way to run `MonadReader`, you could define your own type class for this. Approximately like this (untested):

```
class MonadReader r m => RunReader r m | m -> r where
  type Output m a :: *
  runReader' :: m a -> r -> Output m a

instance RunReader r ((->) r) where
  type Output ((->) r) a = a
  runReader' = ($)

instance Monad m => RunReader r (ReaderT r m) where
  type Output (ReaderT r m) a = m a
  runReader' = runReaderT

instance RunReader r m => RunReader r (MaybeT m) where
  type Output (MaybeT m) a = Output m (Maybe a)
  runReader' = runMaybeT . runReader'

-- any other instances
```

and then `runReader' testOne` and `runReader' testTwo` will work. See ["Associated data and type families"](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html) for an explanation of use of `type` here.

Comment: using it as a function defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to accomplish though

Comment: Probably whoever told you "(->) r is an instance of the Reader monad" meant that it is an instance of `MonadReader` (alternately, they could have meant it's isomorphic to the `Reader` type). So you can write `testAbstract :: MonadReader m => m String String` with the same definition. But there is no general way to "run" a `MonadReader`.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to show how you could _create_ such an abstraction.

Comment: Will those `Output` instances really be accepted? Don't they take too many indices? Or am I confused?

Comment: @dfeuer Note the kind of `Output m`. You could also write is as `type Output m a :: *`. There is a similar example with `data GMap k` in the linked documentation.

Comment: @dfeuer You are right about the edit, though; thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried compiling it yet, but I'm surprised. A free-standing type family `type family Foo a :: * -> *` will, I believe, only accept instances that reduce to first-class types of that kind. So `type instance Foo Int = Either Bool`, but not `type instance Foo Int a = a`.

Comment: @dfeuer I may be confused myself, but I can't test it today. If it doesn't work, I think `type Output m a :: *` should?

Comment: I tried compiling it; no dice. A partially applied data family is "first class". A partially applied type family, on he other hand, is second-class like a partially applied type synonym.